# Django custom template tag being cached

Tags: django, templates, caching

I won't be offended if you just send a link to where this has already been answered.  I haven't found an answer to this.

I'm working on a site where a [cached template loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader) is enabled.  They have a custom template tag that they call on many pages, and one of the values passed to this tag is the unique article ID of the page that called it.  The problem is that the cached template loader seems to be caching the values too, so even though each page is passing its article ID to the tag, the tag is using the cached article ID.

Is there a way to disable the cached template loader for a single template tag?

Here is some code if it's helpful:

This is the cached template loader setting:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', (
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    )),
)
```

When I comment out this setting and restart the server, the issue goes away, so I know it has "something" to do with caching.

That doc linked above also talks about making sure template tags are [thread-safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#thread-safety-considerations).  Is this because of how the template gets stored in the cache?  What I take from that note about thread-safety is that values passed to template tags shouldn't be assigned to the node itself, but to the render_context.  Am I on the right track?

Here is a sample of what my code is doing:

Calling the tag on page 1:

```
{% my_tag article_id="{{object.article_id}}" %}
```

Calling the tag on page 2:

```
{% my_tag article_id="{{object.article_id}}" %}
```

In both of the above cases, object.article_id is a template variable that contains the article ID for the page calling the template tag.

Below is the template tag code (simplified).

```
@register.tag(name="my_tag")
def do_my_tag(parser, token):

    article_id = None
    values = token.split_contents()
    kwargs = get_kwargs(values[1:])

    if "article_id" in kwargs:
        article_id = kwargs["id"]

    return DoMyTagNode(article_id)

class DoMyTagNode(template.Node):

    def __init__(self, article_id):
        self.article_id = article_id
        self.template = get_template('path/to/template.html')

    def render(self, context):
        article_id = Template(self.article_id).render(context)

        context.update({ 'article_id': article_id })

        return render_to_string(self.template, context)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the `django.template.loaders.cached.Loader` in development since it means changes to your html files aren't picked up, requiring you to restart the server. That's most likely your issue since you haven't really provided much more.

The cached loader isn't caching the output of your templates, it's caching the templates from the filesystem. They will still behave as normal as without the loader so that's not your issue. The loader doesn't cache the output of your custom tag.